# Overflow-x and Overflow-y not working for Android 4.3 or below

Tags: android, html, css, overflow

I'm creating a menu for my website in which I am using

1) `SKEW,POSITION:ABSOLUTE and OVERFLOW:HIDDEN`  for

```
main-div{width:90%;height:100%}
```

2) `OVERFLOW-Y:AUTO` for `sub-div(width:130%;height:auto)`

```
<div class="main-div">
<div class="sub-div">
</div>
</div>
```

Its working fine in IOS,Android 4.4 and chrome browser....but i got some issues with android version 4.3 and below.....

The sub-div is hidden in browser but not in device.

Can anyone help me in this issue